# Issue with forward search (single PDF but multiple tex files) Emacs + SyncTex + Evince

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, multiple-files

I have a single master file and several other .tex files are included in this master file.

TeX-source-correlate mode is enabled for forward search.

For the master file forward search is working but when I do it on some other .tex files, Emacs raises an error that says that the corresponding PDF file is not found.

I have included the master file name at the end of every included .tex file.

Comment: How exactly is the master added in the other files?

Comment: @daleif %%%TeX-master : "/path/to/master.tex"

Comment: Remove the extension.

Comment: Did you write that data manually? You should not, use `C-c _` to set the master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TeX-master` requires the path of the master file but *without the extension* (`.tex` is hardcoded).  You can easily specify the master file in secondary files with <kbd>C-C _</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-master-file-ask` <kbd>RET</kbd> or, from the menu bar, `LaTeX > Multifile/Parsing > Set Master File`), as suggested by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186501/issue-with-forward-search-single-pdf-but-multiple-tex-files-emacs-synctex/186510#comment431539_186501).

In addition, I'd suggest you to add

```lisp
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

to your `.emacs` file, as suggested in the very first lines of the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html), so every time you open a new *TeX you will be automatically prompted to select the master file.